# Bullet list inside lstlisting

Tags: latex

I am very new to Latex. I use `lstlisting` package to create grey boxes with code/text.
I'm able to set bold, italic or underline, but I'm not able to add a bullet list inside my box.
I tried the following code, escape char is `%`

```
\begin{lstlisting}
    %\begin{itemize}%
        %\item% Test    // tried also with: %\item Test%
    %\end{itemize}%
\end{lstlisting}
```

Settings for the listing are:

```
\definecolor{mygray}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}
\lstset{ 
  basicstyle=\small,
  backgroundcolor=\color{mygray},
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  breaklines=true,
  escapechar=\%,
  framexleftmargin=1em,
  framexleftmargin=1em,
  framextopmargin=1em,
  framexbottommargin=1em,
  frame=tb, framerule=0pt
}
```

How can I make this work? I guess it has something to do with right escaping, but can't find out how.

Comment: Hi! Isn't `%` used here for commenting??

Comment: No, I used it as escape character, because any text inside `lstlisting` would be printed as plain text, if you want to run a command you need to escape it